# Java: calculating average using JTextField array return 0 everytime

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to write a Java GUI program that calculate average for user-defined number of courses, yet, the array seems to be empty whenever I try to do for example: `System.out.println(gTextFields[0]);` , I could not figure what the problem is, I hope someone can help out.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Swinggg extends JFrame {

double course1 = 90;
double course2 = 80;


private JLabel numOfCoursesLabel;
private JTextField numOfFallCourses;
private JButton clickButton;
private JButton calcAvg;
private JLabel label;
private JTextField textField;
private JLabel gLabel;
private JTextField gTextField;

public Swinggg() {
    super("Title");
    setLayout(null);
    // Setting up the label
    numOfCoursesLabel = new JLabel("Please enter the number of courses that you completed in Fall 17/18: ");
    numOfCoursesLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    Dimension labelSize = numOfCoursesLabel.getPreferredSize();
    numOfCoursesLabel.setBounds(25, 20, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
    add(numOfCoursesLabel);
    // Setting up the text field
    numOfFallCourses = new JTextField(20);
    Dimension textFieldSize = numOfFallCourses.getPreferredSize();
    numOfFallCourses.setBounds(130, 60, textFieldSize.width, textFieldSize.height + 10);
    numOfFallCourses.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    add(numOfFallCourses);
    // Setting up the click button
    clickButton = new JButton("Click");
    Dimension buttonSize = clickButton.getPreferredSize();
    clickButton.setBounds(360, 55, buttonSize.width + 20, buttonSize.height + 10);
    clickButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    add(clickButton);
    // Setting up the calculate average button
    calcAvg = new JButton("Calculate Average");
    Dimension calcAvgSize = calcAvg.getPreferredSize();
    calcAvg.setBounds(180, 100, 200, 40);
    calcAvg.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    add(calcAvg);

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    clickButton.addActionListener(handler);
    calcAvg.addActionListener(handler);
    numOfFallCourses.addActionListener(handler);
}


private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int theNumOfCourses = 0;
        int yDynamicPositioning = 120;
        JTextField[] textFields = new JTextField[theNumOfCourses];
        JTextField[] gTextFields = new JTextField[theNumOfCourses];
        if (event.getSource() == clickButton) {
            theNumOfCourses = Integer.parseInt(numOfFallCourses.getText());
            JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[theNumOfCourses];
            textFields = new JTextField[theNumOfCourses];
            JLabel[] gLabels = new JLabel[theNumOfCourses];
            gTextFields = new JTextField[theNumOfCourses];
            for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                yDynamicPositioning = yDynamicPositioning + 35;
                // Course name labels creation
                label = new JLabel("Course Name " + i);
                Dimension labelSize = label.getPreferredSize();
                label.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
                label.setBounds(25, yDynamicPositioning, labelSize.width + 40, labelSize.height);
                add(label);

                // Course name text fields creation
                textField = new JTextField(10);
                textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
                Dimension textFieldSize = textField.getPreferredSize();
                textField.setBounds(160, yDynamicPositioning, textFieldSize.width, textFieldSize.height + 2);
                textFields[i] = textField;
                add(textField);

                // Course grades labels creation
                gLabel = new JLabel("Course Grade " + i);
                Dimension gLabelSize = gLabel.getPreferredSize();
                gLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
                gLabel.setBounds(300, yDynamicPositioning, gLabelSize.width + 40, gLabelSize.height);
                add(gLabel);

                // Course grades text fields creation
                gTextField = new JTextField(10);
                gTextField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
                Dimension gTextFieldSize = gTextField.getPreferredSize();
                gTextField.setBounds(440, yDynamicPositioning, gTextFieldSize.width, gTextFieldSize.height + 2);
                gTextFields[i] = gTextField;
                add(gTextField);


            }
            calcAvg.setBounds(210, yDynamicPositioning + 50, 200, 40);
            System.out.println(gTextFields[0].getText());
            clickButton.setVisible(false);
            setSize(650, 250 + (labels.length * 40) + 40);
            validate();
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        } else if (event.getSource() == calcAvg) {
            int counter = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            try {
                while (counter < gTextFields.length) {
                    sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(gTextFields[counter].getText());
                    System.out.println(gTextFields[0]);
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occurred!");
            }
            double avg = ((course1 + course2) + sum) / (2 + gTextFields.length);
            System.out.println(sum);

        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Swinggg objct = new Swinggg();
    objct.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    objct.setSize(600, 250);
    objct.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you post those two comments as an answer, I promise you an upvote.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think I can do that sense the arrays sizes depend on the user input after pressing the clickButton. Excuse me sir if I did not understand you well.

Comment: Please see more edits to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the listener gets called, it creates an entirely **new** array of JTextFields (two new arrays actually), and so you're trying to extract data from empty JTextFields.

in sum, this is what your listener is doing:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    // create two arrays of JTextField, textFields and gTextFields
    // this happens **every time the listener is called!**

    if (event.getSource() == clickButton) {

        // fill the array with objects and put them into the GUI

    } else if (event.getSource() == calcAvg) {

        // extract data from the JTextField arrays, but **not** the displayed array of fields
        // rather of a new array that has never been added to the GUI

    }
}
```

Instead declare the arrays to be a field of the class, create the JTextFields and place them in the constructor, not in a listener. Use the listener to extract data from them. If you want to hold off displaying the JTextField grid when the program gets created, **still** you should create the grid, put it into a JPanel in your code's constructor, and then in the ActionListener use a CardLayout to swap the grid into view.

---

**EDIT**

You state:

> I don't think I can do that sense the arrays sizes depend on the user input after pressing the clickButton

Then declare the empty arrays as a field, and fill them once in the listener.
But don't create the array more than once in the listener. You will need to take care to do this. You can check for null to prevent this from happening.

e.g.,

```
//  fields declared in *class* and are null:
private JTextField[] textFields;
private JTextField[] gTextFields;

    private class TheHandler implements ActionListener 

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == clickButton) {
                // get user input

                if (textFields == null && gTextFields == null) {
                    textFields = new JTextField[someInt];
                    gTextFields = new JTextField[someInt];
                    // use for loop to fill arrays and place into GUI

                }

            } else if (event.getSource() == calcAvg) {

                // extract data from the JTextField arrays,
            }
        }
    }
```

Better still: use a `List<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<>();`. This way you don't need to know the size of the array in advance.

Side note regarding: `setLayout(null);`

While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.

---

**Edit**

Note, if this were my program, I'd try to simplify it further using a JTable to hold my course name / course grade data, and to do the average calculation for me. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Swinggg2 extends JPanel {
    // default table model holds no data, but displays the column header names, course/grade
    private MyTableModel tableModel = new MyTableModel(0);
    private JTable myTable = new JTable(tableModel);

    // get the number of courses in a JSpinner, from 1 to 100
    private JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 100, 1));
    private JTextField averageField = new JTextField(10);

    public Swinggg2() {
        // create our GUI
        // first the top JPanel to get the number of courses
        JPanel courseNumberPanel = new JPanel();
        courseNumberPanel.add(new JLabel("Please enter the number of courses that you completed in Fall 17/18:"));
        courseNumberPanel.add(spinner);
        courseNumberPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Courses") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int rowCount = (int) spinner.getValue();
                tableModel = new MyTableModel(rowCount);
                myTable.setModel(tableModel);
            }
        }));

        // then the JScrollPane to hold the JTable
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(myTable);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // then create the bottom JPanel to calculate and display the average grade
        averageField.setEditable(false);
        JPanel calcAveragePanel = new JPanel();
        calcAveragePanel.add(new JLabel("Calculated Average Grade:"));
        calcAveragePanel.add(averageField);
        calcAveragePanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Calculate Average") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // if user is still editing a cell, STOP editing
                if (myTable.isEditing()) {
                    myTable.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
                }

                // extract the average value from the table model and display it
                double average = tableModel.getAverageGrade();
                String averageText = String.format("%.3f", average);
                averageField.setText(averageText);
            }
        }));

        // give the JPanel a layout and add components to it, top, center, bottom
        int gap = 3;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(gap, gap, gap, gap));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(courseNumberPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(calcAveragePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    // create and show the GUI
    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        Swinggg2 mainPanel = new Swinggg2();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Course Grade Average");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // do everything on the Swing event thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

```
// each row of our JTable holds a Course object's data
class Course {
    private String name;
    private double grade;

    public Course(String name, double grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    // hashcode and equals based on name (or courseNumber)
}
```

```
// table model to hold and display our course data
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
    // Table's column header Strings
    public static final String[] COL_NAMES = {"Course Name", "Course Grade"};

    public MyTableModel(int rowCount) {
        super(COL_NAMES, rowCount);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return COL_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 1) {
            return Double.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

    public void addRow(Course course) {
        Object[] rowData = {course.getName(), course.getGrade()};
        super.addRow(rowData);
    }

    public Course getRow(int rowIndex) {
        //get data, handling nulls carefully
        String name = (String) getValueAt(rowIndex, 0);
        name = name == null? "" : name;
        Object colObject = getValueAt(rowIndex, 1);
        double grade = colObject == null ? 0.0 : (double) colObject;
        return new Course(name, grade);
    }


    public double getAverageGrade() {
        // if no rows, either return 0.0 
        if (getRowCount() == 0) {
            return 0.0;  // ? or throw an exception ?
        }

        // summation variable
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++) {
            // iterate through the table extracting grades and adding to total
            total += getRow(i).getGrade();
        }

        // calculate and return the average
        return total / getRowCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abdullah: you're welcome. I've edited the answer to show another way to approach it -- use a JTable, and do the summation and average calculation within the table's TableModel